# How to make SOLR manipulate the results?

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

For an E-commerce website, we have stored the products as SOLR documents with the following fields and weights:
Title:5
Description:4

For some products, we need to ensure that they appear in the top ten results even if their relevance in the above two fields does not qualify them for being in top 10. For example:
P1, P2, .... P10 are the legitimate products for a given search keword "iPhone". I have S1 ... S100 as sponsored products that want to appear in the top 10. My policy is that only 2 of these 100 sponsored products will be randomly chosen and shown in the top 10 so that the results will be: S5, S31, P1, P2, ... P8. In the next request, the sponsored products that gets slipped in may be S4, S99.

The QueryElevationComponent lets us specify the docIDs for keywords but does not let us randomize the results such that only 2 of the complete set of sponsored docIDs is sent in the results.

Any suggestions for implementing this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case where you will need to issue two separate queries to Solr, one for the legitimate products and another one for the sponsored products. Then you will need to manually manipulate/construct the results based off the two Solr results that are returned so that they meet the expected behavior. I do not know of any way to accomplish this directly in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea that might lead you in the right direction:

You could use a [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) for sorting. Within this FunctionQuery you could check if a result is a sponsored result. If yes, depending on the index (0-99) of the spnsored result and two two-digit-parts of the actual time got by [ms()](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#ms) you can decide to lift the result up or not by returning the score of the initial query or a modified one.

A result is lifted up, if its index is identical to one of the two two-digit-parts.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved pls use elevation component.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component